# get warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type for using pointer to char array in struct

Tags: c, pointers

I get "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" when compiling. How can I don't get that warning?

**Here is some part of source code:**

```
typedef struct
{
    char id[9];
    char fName[9];    
    char lName[9];
    int finalExam;
    int midTerm;
    float quiz1;
    float quiz2;
    float quiz3;
    float totalMark;
} Student;

....
....
....

pointAt = students; // initialize pointer
            float* topMark;
            char* topLname;
            char* topId;
            topMark = &(*pointAt).totalMark;
            topLname = &(*pointAt).lName;
            topId = &(*pointAt).id;
            printf("top guy : %s\n", topLname);
            pointAt += 1;
```

**I get that warning at:**

```
topLname = &(*pointAt).lName;
    topId = &(*pointAt).id;
```

these 2 lines causes that warning, because it points to char array. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&(*pointAt).lName` and `&(*pointAt).id` are of type `char (*)[9]`, while the variables these values are being assigned to are of type `char *`, hence the mismatch.

Get rid of the `&` operator to get an expression of the `char [9]` which will decay to a `char *`.   While you're at it, use the `->` operator to reference the member of a struct pointer:

```
topLname = pointAt->lName;
topId = pointAt->id;
```